# Why are my formtastic translations not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, formtastic

Translations seem to be my greatest enemy:( I have a nice Formtastic form, and a yaml translation file. I've set the translation in the `config/application.rb` like this:

```
config.i18n.available_locales = :nl
config.i18n.default_locale = :nl
```

and a before_filter method in `application_controller.rb` like this:

```
before_filter :set_locale

def set_locale
  session[:locale] = params[:locale] unless params[:locale].nil?
  I18n.locale = session[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end
```

My form looks like this (it's written in haml):

```
= semantic_form_for Ad.new do |f|       
  .holder
    = f.inputs do
      = f.input :name

    = f.inputs do
      = f.input :reason
```

and finaly my nl.yml looks like this:

```
nl:
  formtastic:
    titles:
      ads:
        reason: "Waarom verkoop je het?"
    labels:
      ads:
        reason: "Waarom verkoop je het?"
    hints:
      ads:
        reason: "Waarom verkoop je het?"
    placeholders:
      ads:
        reason: "Waarom verkoop je het?"
```

As you can see I've added the same translation to all these keys Formtastic provides but none show up, the label remains `Reason` and there is no placeholder text. For as far as I can tell I've done exactly what the Formtastic readme prescribes. I'm using formtastic (2.2.1) with rails (3.2.8). If I add activerecord translations to the `nl.yml` the label does get translated. Why don't the formtastic translations work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little lame, but the problem turned out to be in the `ads` part. I shouldn't have pluralized `ad`. This works fine:

```
nl:
  formtastic:
    titles:
      ad: // Mind the difference here: no 's'
        reason: "Waarom verkoop je het?"
    labels:
      ad:
        reason: "Waarom verkoop je het?"
    hints:
      ad:
        reason: "Waarom verkoop je het?"
    placeholders:
      ad:
        reason: "Waarom verkoop je het?"
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm not quite sure but have you tried something like:

```
nl:
  formtastic:
    ads:
      reason: "Waarom verkoop je het?"
...
```

since the model class is *Ad* here and i18n should somehow reflect the model structur?

Comment: That wasn't it, but your answer gave me an insight. I pluralized "add", where I shouldn't have done so... Thanks for the hint!